# How to number list elements in Elm?

Tags: list, recursion, elm

Given the following list

```
  List Records
```

where `Record` is

```
   type Record
   = RecordA A
   | RecordB B
```

and `A` and `B` are type aliases with `pos` field:

```
  type alias A =
  { pos : Maybe Int
  , type : Char
  }
```

how would I create a new list that numbers subsequent `A` and `B` records? I want to have `pos = 1` in the first `A` record, `pos = 2` in the second `A` record, `pos = 1` in the first `B` record, etc. (The original list comes without numbers in the `pos` field.)

This is a solution for a language that allows mutation.

```js
let countA = 0;
let countB = 0;
for (el of my_array) {
    el.pos = (el.type == 'A') ? ++countA : ++countB;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert any iterative algorithm using mutable variables into a recursive one that don't quite easily by just making the mutable variables function arguments:

```
enumerate : List Record -> Int -> Int -> List Record
enumerate list countA countB =
    case list of
        [] ->
            []

        (RecordA el) :: rest ->
            RecordA { el | pos = Just countA } :: enumerate rest (countA + 1) countB

        (RecordB el) :: rest ->
            RecordB { el | pos = Just countB } :: enumerate rest countA (countB + 1)
```

This is not tail recursive however, and will therefore overflow the stack on larger lists. It's also a bit inconvenient to have to specify the initial counts every time we use this. We can solve both by using an inner function and adding an accumulator argument to it:

```
enumerate : List Record -> List Record
enumerate list =
    let
        aux els acc posA posB =
            case list of
                [] ->
                    acc

                (RecordA el) :: rest ->
                    aux rest (RecordA { el | pos = Just posA } :: acc) (posA + 1) posB

                (RecordB el) :: rest ->
                    aux rest (RecordB { el | pos = Just posB } :: acc) posA (posB + 1)
    in
    aux list [] 0 0
```

You seem to have some deeper data modeling issues here though, but it also doesn't look like your actual types, so hopefully you'll figure that out eventually too. This should at least get you a bit closer.

Comment: In the end I have made a (tail) recursive call that copies (and mutates) elements from the source list to the destination list - one at a time. (And then I will probably reverse the destination list and put it all in an array).  I only need to do it once when a huge chunk of data arrives from the server so I think it's acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy response: A map expression might, in essence, do what you want. I haven't checked this thoroughly because I was as well too lazy for the boilerplate to make it actually compile in an ellie though:

```
List.map (\n -> RecordA (A(Just n) 'a')) (List.range 1 5)
```

If I get you correctly, you *have* a list containing both `A` and `B` types? Then you might want to pattern match on the types in the function that is mapped over the list (the `(\n -> RecordA (A(Just n) 'a'))` part), maybe construct two lists and `zip` them together. But as @glennsl already said, the design leaves some questions open.

Comment: The problem is counting the elements; you cannot mutate data (=maintain a counter) so I think I do need a recursive call (?)